# Save data/page to a list in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am new to react native and have a problem.

i have two pages rockSetting.js & "myFavoriteSetting.js".

I want to have a onButtonPress in the rockSetting pages that creates a list in the myFavoriteSettings page with a title"rock" and link to the rockSetting page.

well,  basically i want to be able to add a list item to a list in another file.
something like.. 
page 1 functionality : When a button is pressed create a list item in page 2
page 2 : Gets the list item.

How should i think about this problem ?

Comment: I think better solution is to use redux.

Comment: From what I understood, it seems you want to add navigation into your React Native project? I'd recommend you use something like [React-Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org)

Comment: well,  basically i want to be able to add a list item to a list in another file.
something like.. 
page 1 functionality : When a button is pressed create a list item in page 2
page 2 : Gets the list item.

Comment: @MeysamIzadmehr i will check redux, any specific part you think i should read about ?

Comment: In your case simplest example of redux enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to share data between different components (pages), you can actually use Flux or Redux, but Redux is kind of an upgrade based on Flux (and of course Redux may be a bit more complicated), you can read the tutorial here, but it's gonna be long, so you should be patient and learn many new definitions about Redux:

https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

**ADDED EXPLANATION ON REDUX:**

Actually, Flux and Redux both have a definition of a Store, which has kind of global scope, and it is a "single source of truth" (meaning there's only one Store, but of course you can store a lot of variables in that Store). In your case, you may store `favoriteData` in the Store as blank at first, then when Button on RockSetting is clicked, set `favoriteData` of the Store to your data, then the MyFavoriteSetting should display correctly.

Redux and Flux will give you lots of new definitions and ideas, a bit complicated at first, but after you master the architecture, you are "there" and you can apply it everywhere in your React/React Native projects. There's still many interesting points for you to find out there, be patient because it's worth the effort, though!

======================

However, you can still use pure react way to do that, passing props from parent component to child component. In more details, you can create 3 components: ParentSetting, RockSetting and MyFavoriteSetting as follows:

ParentSetting.js

```
import React from 'react';

class ParentSetting extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // ...
    this.state = {
      favoriteData: 'no data yet',
    }

  }

  updateFavoriteSetting = () => {
    // We will change state for updating the MyFavoriteSetting component here
    let list_data = "any data you like";
    // actually, you can set an array or object, then we will loop through the object to render data correctly in MyFavoriteSetting. You can also add some react element (which contains some View and Button, just like you described)

    this.setState({
      favoriteData: list_data
    });
  }

  render(){
    // We render the 2 children components: RockSetting and MyFavoriteSetting
    // please consider the way to pass props into those 2 ^^
    return (
      <View>
        <RockSetting updateFavoriteSetting={this.updateFavoriteSetting} />
        <MyFavoriteSetting favoriteData={this.state.favoriteData} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

RockSetting.js

```
import React from 'react';

class RockSetting extends React.Component {
  // Please render your button properly, this is just an example of how to bind click function to it
  render(){
    return (
      <Button onClick={this.props.updateFavoriteSetting} />
    )
  }
}
```

MyFavoriteSetting.js

```
import React from 'react';

class MyFavoriteSetting extends React.Component {
  // Please render your button properly, this is just an example of how to bind click function to it
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        {this.props.favoriteData}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

You can also learn more about React before coding with React-native, they use the same React's way

If you still have problems, please post here and describe more about them, we will try to fix together, thanks

Comment: first of all...thank you so much for taking the time to help ! 
When i do the "  // We render the 2 children components: RockSetting and MyFavoriteSetting
    // please consider the way to pass props into those 2 ^^" It makes the RockSetting and MyFavoriteSetting show up in the ParentSettings instead. But the functionality works.

Comment: Ah..that's right, I just explained how we can connect 2 or more components together. Since now those 2 Setting components appear on 2 different pages, then you may consider using Redux or Flux. I am now editing my above answer to explain a bit more about Redux!